# Processing nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a nested list with the below structure:[image]

Each `$mu` is a vector of 15 numbers. **How can I calculate the average of each of the 15 elements across 1000 `$mu`'s?**

I know I can access the `$mu`'s with `hb.post.PT1$compdraw[[1]]$mu`, but how can I extract or loop over them to execute functions?

I've been trying stuff like this without success:

```
lapply(hb.post.PT1$compdraw, function(x) lapply(hb.post.PT1$compdraw[[x]]$mu, function(x) mean))
```

My apologies, I cannot post example list data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
hb.post.PT1$compdraw %>%
 purrr::map(function(x) {
   mean(x$mu)
 }) %>% unlist
```

Comment: or just `map_dbl(hb.post.PT1$compdraw , ~mean(.$mu))`

Comment: Nice @Moody_Mudskipper! I'm a `purrr` beginner.

Answer (score 2):

You are already looping through each list element with the first `lapply`. So based on your structure each iteration of the loop will be a list of 2 elements (`mu` and `rooti`). So you only need one `lapply`:

```
ll <- list(list(mu = runif(15), root = runif(10)), list(mu = runif(15), runif(10)))

str(ll)
#List of 2
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ mu  : num [1:15] 0.314 0.614 0.228 0.594 0.447 ...
#  ..$ root: num [1:10] 0.73 0.496 0.266 0.599 0.917 ...
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ mu: num [1:15] 0.134 0.244 0.507 0.771 0.934 ...
#  ..$   : num [1:10] 0.818 0.138 0.83 0.509 0.914 ...

lapply(ll, function(x) mean(x$mu))
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.4264001
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.4526724
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with `purrr::imap` from the tidyverse. We can apply a function that creates a `tbl` with the list index and the mean of that index's `mu` vector, and bind them into one dataframe for easy display.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(12345)
testlist <- list(
  list(mu = rnorm(15), rooti = rnorm(15)),
  list(mu = rnorm(15), rooti = rnorm(15)),
  list(mu = rnorm(15), rooti = rnorm(15)),
  list(mu = rnorm(15), rooti = rnorm(15)),
  list(mu = rnorm(15), rooti = rnorm(15))
)
str(testlist[1:2])
#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ mu   : num [1:15] 0.586 0.709 -0.109 -0.453 0.606 ...
#>   ..$ rooti: num [1:15] 0.817 -0.886 -0.332 1.121 0.299 ...
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ mu   : num [1:15] 0.812 2.197 2.049 1.632 0.254 ...
#>   ..$ rooti: num [1:15] 1.461 -1.413 0.567 0.583 -1.307 ...

testlist %>%
  imap_dfr(.f = ~ tibble(index = .y, mu_mean = mean(.x$mu)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   index mu_mean
#>   <int>   <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.0341
#> 2     2  0.448 
#> 3     3  0.146 
#> 4     4 -0.130 
#> 5     5  0.244
```

Created on 2018-05-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Could be overkill for this case but for this kind of problem in general it's good to remember about `purrr::transpose`

```
map(transpose(hb.post.PT1$compdraw)$mu,mean)
```